# How to alias field names in a Spring Batch Bean?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-batch

From the documentation, I see that one can alias an entire Spring bean.
How can one alias the field names of a bean?

I have a CSV file that has column names A1, A2, A3...

The Spring Batch program expects X1, X2, X3...

I want to map A1->X1, A2->X2, A3->X3... without hardcoding.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper` is based on reflection and uses the Java Beans naming conventions to convert columns in the CSV file to fields in your domain objects. This mapper is a bit smart in some way as it allows fuzzy matching (see [its javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.html)).

However, if column names in the input file are completely different from field names in your domain object and you want the mapping to be dynamic,  you need to create a custom `FieldSetMapper` that loads the mapping meta-data from a properties file for example and maps columns to fields dynamically at runtime.

Comment: How would I specify "FieldSetMapper that loads the mapping meta-data from a properties file". Would the `FieldSetMapper` have its fields `autowired`?

Comment: You first create a file that contains the mapping meta-data (`a1=x1\na2=x2\n...`). Then create a class that implements `FieldSetMapper` that reads that file and maps columns from the `FieldSet` to corresponding fields in your domain object based on the mapping defined in the meta-data file. Once that done, you set your custom implementation on the `FlatFileItemReader`. This allows you to dynamically change the mapping without recompiling your app.

Comment: Here is a sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/order/internal/mapper/CustomerFieldSetMapper.java. You just need to add the dynamism of loading the mapping meta-data from an external file.